# jQuery, js, ajax, div element wrong height

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, height

I've interesting problem. I load some data via ajax using jQuery (list of lines), and then put them into the div, which finally gets appended to the document. When I try to do sth like this

```
doc.append(myDiv);
console.log(myDiv.height());
```

I get wrong height (document inspector shows different value). But when I wait (eg. 750ms), and then try to get height, it's ok.

And there is my question, am I doing sth wrong, or is it normal behaviour of the browser? (I'm using Chrome)

Cheers.

Up,
To clear things up, I do sth like this:

```
success: function() {
       for(line in data){
            doing sth on line, and then append to myDiv
       }
       myDiv.height()
      }
```

Comment: Maybe your div has `display: none` at the time you check it's height?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of ajax response not loaded. Try using ajax with `async:false`.
check this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the data to be loaded in the DIV and then only do the alert. I am not sure what your full code is but looks like this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

try getting height with direct javascript without jquery. I have notices that some times jquery height and width function are not correct. try these:

```
myDiv.get(0).offsetHeight;
```